# Using a (minecraft) plugin, how can I modify the maximum durability of an Item? (Commands work as well)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make a plugin with custom recipes (I have that part, thank you very much) to create some pickaxes with insane durability, but I don't want it to be unbreakable, since that breaks the whole point of Survival. It just bases the texture on a Netherite Pickaxe.

Comment: Do you want to make a commands system or a plugin? They're two different things and it's not clear which one you're looking for.

Comment: if ur looking to make a really plugin this probably isn't a good place to ask

Comment: commands? if it can edit nbt tags im fine with it.